# Anyone using VSCODE for developing springboot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

I was using Eclipse for developing Spring boot project. Eclipse is soooo slow in running, so I decided to change my ide. Most people recommend intellij which support majority of extensions for java. However, it is not for free (I know there is free version, but some said compare to Eclipse there are no difference between them. maybe? idk..) and some people said it is a bit slow (not like eclipse but little bit slow). I know people are not using VScode for spring boot, they support some extensions yet compare to intellij it is almost zero base starting. However, upside for vscode is free and light for developing small (maybe middle?) size project. What would you recommend?

additionally, right now I am testing whether vscode can run spring boot

[image]

vscode cannot import any annotaiton or collection or anything just loading kept showing.
anyone know solution? since almost no one is using vscode for java there seems to be no information

Comment: Could you see a thumb-up icon in the status bar?

Comment: @Sheng Chen Yes, I add jdk to seetings.json not nothing solved

Comment: Have you installed the related extensions? And could you have a look at the [official tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot)

Comment: @Steven yes, I installed all the java extension and spring boot extensions. Importing annotation and collection were working when I created brand new project, yet it fails when I import project and tried to edit it or add dependency of mybatis.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using vscode for springboot+vue projects. everything works fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32352065)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try disabling spring boot extension pack and "Clean Java Language server workspace". It help me avoid that problem.

You can refer to here: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/808

Comment: You might want to add a few more words to support your answer (official reference, details on how to effectively disable the extension pack)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).